# Third party cookie - read from other domain

Tags: json, cookies

I'm creating third party cookie with `<img src="http://example.com/test.php" />`

test.php:

```
if($_GET['r']) {
    header('Content-type: image/gif');
    // echo transparent 1x1 pixel
    exit;
} else {
    setcookie('name', md5(time()), time()+60*60*24*30, '/');
    $url = 'http://example.com/test.php?r=1';
    header('Location: '.$url);
   exit;
}
```

This code creates third-party cookie. Is there any method to read created cookie through javascript from a different domain than example.com?

Answer (score 3):

No. JavaScript only has access to the cookies for the current document, not for any of its dependencies.

If this wasn't the case then authors could load an image from any website you might have an account on, read the cookie with JavaScript, Ajax it to their server, and then have a copy of your current login token for that site. It would be a huge security hole.